# Differential equation of Van Gorder type for zeta of global fields, or: Does the zeta function of a global field satisfy a differential equation?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, algebraic-number-theory, differential-equations

Let
\begin{equation*}
\zeta(s):=\prod_{p\text{ prime}}\frac{1}{1-p^{-s}}
\end{equation*}
be the Riemann zeta function. Van Gorder has shown that $\zeta$ satisfies a differential equation
\begin{equation*}
T(\zeta(s)-1)=\frac{1}{s-1}\text{,}
\end{equation*}
where $T$ is an infinite differential operator.

*Robert A. Van Gorder*, MR 3276353 [**Does the Riemann zeta function satisfy a differential equation?**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jnt.2014.08.013), *J. Number Theory* **147** (2015), 778--788.

Let $k=\mathbb{F}_{p}(x)[y]/\pi$ be a global field, where $\pi\in\operatorname{Spec}(\mathbb{F}_{p}(x)[y])$ is a maximal ideal, and let
\begin{equation*}
\zeta_{k}(s):=\prod_{\mathfrak{m}\in\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{O}_{k})\text{ maximal}}\frac{1}{1-N_{\mathfrak{m}}^{-s}}
\end{equation*}
be the associated zeta function, where $N_{m}:=\#\mathcal{O}_{k}/\mathfrak{m}$. I wonder if results similar to Van Gorder's can be obtained for $\zeta_{k}$.

Does the zeta function of a global field satisfy a differential equation?

Comment: Zeta functions of function fields are rational functions in $p^s$.

Comment: I know. But is there a general way to derive a functional equation they satisfy?

Comment: Probably. An easy way to see there exists one is to note that for a function $F(s)=f(p^s)$, with $f(x)\in\mathbb C(x)$, both $F$ and $F'$ belong to $\mathbb C(p^s)$, which means they are algebraically dependent over $\mathbb C$.